# How to make maven use separate target folders for every version of program?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build

As example, i have program with version 0.0.1. Maven must create separate folder for it - "target/0.0.1/" instead of "target/". It must be done for version "0.0.2", "0.0.3", etc.

I use Eclipse & it's Maven:
Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200

JDK 1.8.0_172

Comment: How exactly do you combine multiple versions of your program in one project?

Comment: Why do you need such thing?

Comment: This is not how maven is intended to be used.  Please add a full description of the problem you try to solve with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maven doesn't work that way, and trying to do something like that will lead to a path of suffering. Options I see include

- Creating a separate assembly (and output Jar) for each version (see [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html))
- [Create a multi-project reactor](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) with a separate output configuration for every project. Keep common code in one project that you link as dependency from the others. Possibly use the [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/usage.html) to re-link the packages in your common project into the individual output projects

As you can see, both of these approaches are pretty hacky and require advanced Maven skills. It would be much easier to have parameterized builds where you pass in the output version. But that would make sense on a CI server like Jenkins.

Comment: Up voted for "path of suffering". My rule of thumb is if Maven doesn't do something a certain way by default, don't bother to try to encourage it to change. I value my sanity.

Comment: Does exist any analog of Maven which can make separate target folders?

Comment: You would probably need some more imperative build tool. Possibly gradle, or (shudder) ant